# Regex class got stuck by infinite loop while(true)

Tags: java, regex, while-loop

I just started java.util.regex topic. I could execute the following code and getting the satisfactory results. I have used infinite loop in the code and trying to break by giving a condition. However it is not breaking somehow. Any thoughts?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class RegEx {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        //using system input for Pattern and Matcher classes
        Scanner regex = new Scanner(System.in);

        while(true){
            System.out.println("regex please: ");
            Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile(regex.nextLine());
            System.out.println("input please: ");
            Matcher m1 = p1.matcher(regex.nextLine());
            boolean b2 = m1.matches();
            System.out.println("your input \""+m1.group()+"\" is matching and "+b2);

            if(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("does it match: ").equals("Yes")){
                System.out.println("take rest now");
                break;
            }//note sure why this condition is not working
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, did you type **Yes** into the dialog?

Comment: Yes, I did. Surprisingly, I am not getting the pop up.

Comment: I am getting the pop up only after removing the code for Pattern and Matcher objects.

Comment: This is entirely unanswerable unless you tell us what input and what regexp you're using.  Voting to close.

Comment: I am using java.util.regex class. Please note that I am using jdk 1.8 and netbeans

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
if(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("does it match: ").trim().equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
{
//your code
}
```

Comment: The problem is input dialogbox does not seem calling. After the string matching, the code is stuck.

Comment: @user9432866: I have tested it on my PC by running the code in Eclipse, the pop up does appear, if you run from Eclipse try to reduce all your windows and you will see that popup! How do you run it?

Comment: I run it in Netbeans. If I remove the (Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile(regex.nextLine());
                System.out.println("input please: ");
                Matcher m1 = p1.matcher(regex.nextLine());
                boolean b2 = m1.matches();
                System.out.println("your input \""+m1.group()+"\" is matching and "+b2);) code, I am getting the popup. Only problem when I use this code.

Answer (score 0):

Just type `Yes` **without space** and note that the `Y` is in uppercase in the following pop-up and press on the `OK` button.

[image]

When you do this, the condition in the `if` will become `true` and your code will output in the console the string `take rest now` before leaving the loop thanks to the `break` statement.

```
if(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("does it match: ").equals("Yes")){
       System.out.println("take rest now");
       break;
}
```